# Storing Images in Postgres DB Store RefineryCMS with Dragonfly

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, refinerycms, dragonfly-gem

My application is a refineryCMS which is been hosted on the heroku server . I need to store the images on the postgres DB store. I got one gem [dragonfly-activerecord](https://github.com/mezis/dragonfly-activerecord) , but not able to keep it on database . I tried:

Configure Dragonfly itself (in `config/initializers/dragonfly.rb`, typically):

```
require 'dragonfly-activerecord/store'

Dragonfly.app.configure do
 # ... your existing configuration here
 datastore Dragonfly::ActiveRecord::Store.new
```

We need to integrate this gem into refineryCMS.. If we can store images in database for cms that will be great help for host like heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution along with the [dragonfly-activerecord fork](https://github.com/arpit-clarion/dragonfly-activerecord) . Just go to `config/initializers/refinery/images.rb` 
Here is a code to do it. First follow  [dragonfly-activerecord fork](https://github.com/arpit-clarion/dragonfly-activerecord) steps

In Gemfile:

`gem 'dragonfly-activerecord' , git: "git://github.com/arpit-clarion/dragonfly-activerecord.git"`
 and

`bundle`

`rails generate migration add_dragonfly_storage`

In the migration file add this code

```
require 'dragonfly-activerecord/migration'

class AddDragonflyStorage < ActiveRecord::Migration
  include Dragonfly::ActiveRecord::Migration
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate` and add this code:

```
config/initializers/refinery/images.rb
# encoding: utf-8
require 'dragonfly-activerecord/store'
Refinery::Images.configure do |config|
  #...... Your configuration ....
  config.custom_backend_class = 'Dragonfly::ActiveRecord::Store'
  config.custom_backend_opts = {}
  #...... Your configuration ....
end
```

This will change the whole system folder structure set into database. No need to any buckets .

**Keep in mind that this system is for those applications which has less images to store as it generates big chunks in db and it converts images on request time.**

Comment: I have solved this problem by forking the gem and updating images.rb under initializer directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use Amazon S3 to store images? It works great with Heroku : http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/heroku

Comment: The guidlines are so clear about amazone s3 , but its comes with cost too. What I want to do is to store the chunk in to db so that I can manage small applications system storage in db it self.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! Could you write this solution as a guide in Refinery CMS repository? https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/tree/master/doc/guides

Comment: I have proposed this change.  Thank you  @Brice